# What does bad Request with error 400 means in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, error-handling, devops, kibana

I was entering data into my elastic through dev_tool console using command POST elastic/_doc/1,
But faced an issue that said Bad request and error 400 . I am attaching the output below [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtZO3.jpg)

I tried to make a index with the data and expected output 201 i.e created

Answer (score 0):

You can only include a single object/document when creating new documents using POST.

You should add a new line character on line 14 and it should work.